FEDEX API integration in laravel
I am trying to implement Fedex APIs in laravel for national and international shipments.
I am having issues with shipment create API. sometimes it works, sometimes not. The payload body is so extensive and I don't understand most of it.

I am calling get service types API
then rate quotes API
then create shipment.

How do I setup my create shipment API payload, so it works on any origin destination?
Can anyone help me with this?
I have tried sending whole payload, but still it works on some origin destination combination, and with some, it doesn't work. I get multiple types of errors. Mostly I get couldn't process request and contact support, even on production API keys.

did you contact support?

Their API support team has been very helpful for us, the few times that we've had to call over the years, for SOAP and now the REST API. We've crossed some surprises with the new API, such as some string lengths are limited, some inputs that could take values such as 5.25 when using the SOAP API can only take whole numbers now in the new REST API, etc, etc. You can see a full request payload example at their site if it might be helpful? ... on the left side of that page, click the Create Shipment link.

after studying whole documentation, not easy, i got everything working
